# Empty BindingSource problem

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, strongly-typed-dataset, bindingsource

I have a problem with binding data using BindingSource, typed dataset and DataGridView. My problem is: BindingSource, therefore grid, is empty after binding data (bindingSource.Count is 0). I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'd be very happy if anyone could help me with this. My application structure is like this: I have two assemblies, one is Winforms UI and other is database class library.

**UI**

- DataGridView, datasource as BindingSource
- BindingSource, datasource = DBAssembly.typedDataset, datamember = DBAssembly.typedDataset.myTable

**Database assembly**

- Sql Server CE database
- Typed Dataset
- DB class for database operations

**UI Code**

*OnLoad*

```
this.db = new DB(); 
db.BindData();
```

**DB Code**

*constructor*

```
create typedDataSet object 
create typedDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableTableAdapter object 
create typedDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager object
```

*BindData()*

```
this.myTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.typedDataSet.MyTable)
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing to ask would be: what is `this.typedDataSet.MyTable.Rows.Count`? i.e. did the adapter do anything? If not, it has nothing to do with the binding.

Assuming it is non-empty, then what **exact** code are you using to set up `DataSource` and `DataMember`? I expect it should be:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = this.typedDataSet;
bindingSource.DataMember = "MyTable";
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Alternatively, you could set the `bindingSource`'s DataSource to `this.typedDataSet.MyTable` and leave the table blank.

Basically, I expect that you've told it the **type** of data to anticipate, but so far you haven't actually given it the data-set/data-table you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

*Basically, I expect that you've told it the type of data to anticipate, but so far you haven't actually given it the data-set/data-table you want to use.*

Marc you were right about this one. I hade to create a public DataSet property in my DB class and use it as DataSource of BindingSource to make this work. Thanks for the help.